# WordPress: IP Address Showing in Browser (not homepage though)

Tags: browser, ip, wordpress

So I've set up and configured WordPress on an Ubuntu home server.  I have a domain name and everything seems to be working fine with one exception.  Though the domain name shows in the browser of the WordPress home page (e.g. http://www.blahblahblah.com) whenever I click on one of the links within the same page (WordPress login for instance) the IP of my server shows in the browser (e.g. http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx//wordpress/wp-login.php).  I've followed various tutorials etc. but haven't yet solved the problem.

Does anyone know how I might solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You likely used the IP address originally when you set up the site.  See the second paragraph of the "If you forget to change the locations" section of the following page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#If_you_forget_to_change_the_locations for how to switch it to the domain name instead.

Comment: Note: You might get more people to answer your questions if you accepted the answers to some of your other ones.  You currently have not accepted _any_ answers to any of your questions and people don't like to write answers that won't be accepted.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I'll give this a try and verify later.  Also, thanks for pointing out that I'd previously neglected to accept answers.  Was not my intention to overlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Login your wordpress admin page
2. Go to `Setting` -> `General`
3. Check `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)`, they should be as follow

   ```
   WordPress Address (URL) = http://www.blahblahblah.com/wordpress
   Site Address (URL) = http://www.blahblahblah.com
   ```

Comment: My blog is wordpress too, I fight with that for like a week, LOL!!